# DateTime convert to Date and then back to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date, datetimepicker

I use this to convert DateTime value into Date and then I add 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 to make sure whole day is taken into consideration when counting stuff. I'm pretty sure it's wrong way of doing things. What would be the right way?

```
        DateTime varObliczOd = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Value.ToShortDateString() + " 00:00:00");
        DateTime varObliczDo = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataDo.Value.ToShortDateString() + " 23:59:59");
```

Comment: Could you explain the context this is being used in, please

Comment: What are you trying to do with these dates. If you just don't want the real time on there you can just do dateTimeVar.Date which will give you the date with 12:00AM on the end and you can get the end of the day with dateTimeVar.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)

Comment: I'm using this to provide this dates to Sql Database. It's important so that it gets all transactions for time between 00 and 23:59 (although they work only 8 to 18 but i would prefer to cover whole day)

Comment: Especially that sometimes 00:00:00 is used to write transactions made by system and not people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if `dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd` is of type `DateTime`, You can use:

```
dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Date
```

to get the date part only (time will be 00:00:00...).
If you want to get the very last tick of the date, you can use:

```
dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)
```

but you really better work with the next date (.AddDays(1)).

In any case, there is no need to convert to string and back to DateTime.

Comment: Great, I can't work with .AddDays(1) only because it will take into consideration next day transactions (some stuff is written in db done on 00:00:00)

Comment: What i meant is that if you use the dates for range check, you can pull all maching records whose timestamp complies with: 
StartOfTomorrow > timestamp >= startOfToday .
Working with the last tick of the day should also work well, it just smells bad.

Comment: True, i should have used timestamp < startOfTommorow to make sure 00:00 isn't used for the next day.

Answer (score 5):

DateTime objects have a [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property which might be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following properties / methods on a DateTime object to get your values :

```
DateTime varObliczOd = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Date;
DateTime varObliczDo = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.AddDayes(1).AddTicks(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know why you're needing it, but this would work.

```
DateTime varObliczOd = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Date;
DateTime varObliczDo = varObliczOd.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Using the `Date` attribute and then manipulating them directly to create the required time component - no need to bother with parsing and conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Date property of the DateTime object to accomplish what you need.

```
DateTime varObliczOd = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Value.Date;
DateTime varObliczDo = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataDo.Value.Date.AddDays(1);
```

If you really want it to end at 23:59:59 you can do:

```
DateTime varObliczDo = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataDo.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Will set varObliczDo to be your ending date with no time plus one day (at midnight). So if `dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataDo` was `2010-03-05 16:12:12` it would now be `2010-03-06 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? I've typed this out of my head, there are probably some mistakes in the code.

```
DateTime varObliczOd = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.AddSeconds(-dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Seconds).AddMinutes(-dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Minutes).AddHours(-dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Hours);

DateTime varObliczDo  = new DateTime(dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataDo.Year, dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataDo.Month, dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataDoDay, 23, 59, 59);
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime newDate = new DateTime( oldDate.Year, oldDate.Month, oldDate.Day, 23, 59,59 )
    DateTime newDate = new DateTime( oldDate.Year, oldDate.Month, oldDate.Day, 0, 0, 0 )

Answer (score 0):

You could work with TimeSpan:

```
DateTime varObliczOd = dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd - new TimeSpan(dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Hours, dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Minutes, dateTimeWycenaPortfelaObliczDataOd.Seconds);
```

Like that you avoid at least the parsing, which can fail depending on the local culture settings.

Comment: Yes it failed on one workstation and i knew it will be that. I used accepted solution as it seemed better.

Comment: Which solution you take is a matter of preferences, your accepted solution is nice to read in code, but it uses several operations to calculate the result while mine uses just one. Of course, what is exactly behind this one operation I also can not tell you ^^